# How can stable O2 react with other metals on earth

Tags: bond

$O_2$ is a molecule which has achieved a stable configuration, why then can spontaneous reactions occur between O2 and metals on earth ?  Is it that stealing of electrons is preferred above sharing of electrons ?

Comment: One view would be that the free energy of the reacted system is lower than the unreacted metal + oxygen system. Many metal oxides are highly favored.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could apply to almost any reaction! All molecules have a stable electron configuration, N$_2$, benzene, chlorophyll, proteins, DNA etc. We, humans (and all life) are *unstable* with respect to oxidation, but the fact that a reaction is exothermic (spontaneous) does not mean that it has to react quickly. Thermodynamics does not inform us about time-scales just starting and ending energies. A reaction's activation energy can be huge compared to thermal energy and in many cases it often is so reactions proceed exceedingly slowly, e.g man + O$_2$ = CO$_2$+H$_2$O is, thankfully, very, very slow :)  
Note also that the heats of formation of molecules are different, so different types of molecules possess different energy and hence have the ability to react.